# IV with multiple endogeneous variables: how many first stage models?

Tags: instrumental-variables

Assume a model: `y = x1 + x2 + x3` where `x1` is an exogeneous regressor and `x2:x3` are endogeneous.

Suppose theory implies different potential instruments for `x2` and `x3`, (`z1:zN` and `k1:kN` respectively). In IV estimation, should I specify separate first-stage models for each endogeneous variable or should I use all available instruments (including `x1`) for both?

I.e., should I estimate in the first stage:

A) `x2=f(x1, z1:zN, k1:kN)` & `x3=f(x1, z1:zN, k1:kN)`

or

B) `x2=f(z1:zN)` & `x3=f(k1:kN)` (or including `x1` as well in both?)

If I understand correctly, standard iv regression commands in software such as Stata and R seem to only employ one first stage-model (approach A). How should I think about this conceptually? And if B is preferable (always/in certain cases), are there functions in the common software packages that employ this approach?

Comment: Do you mean x3 in the second equation in A) and B)?